# For loop not running for my game in java

Tags: java

```
for(x = mapEdge.getMinX() ; x < mapEdge.getMaxX(); x += 11){        
            if(once){
                yLoop = mapEdge.getMinY() - yLoop;
            }
            for(y = yLoop ; y == yLoop - 11; y -= 11){
                g.drawImage(grass, x, y);
            }
            yLoop = y;
            once = true;
    }
```

---

```
for(y = yLoop ; y == yLoop - 11  ; y -= 11){
    g.drawImage(grass, x, y);

}
```

This loop is not running at all in my code; it just completely bypasses without doing anything.

Comment: You should take a minute to revise what the three expressions in a `for` statement mean...

Comment: you can edit your answer all you want. rgettman's answer will still be the right one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You initialize `y` to `yLoop`, but the condition is `y == yLoop - 11`, which is clearly false the first time, so the loop never runs.

I suspect you want a condition something like this:

```
for(y = yLoop ; y > yLoop - 11  ; y -= 11)
```

Comment: I have the nagging suspicion that the loop you're describing isn't exactly right either.

Comment: @Oli, you're right, the way I've written it, it will execute only once.  But I feel this question is more about using `>` instead of `==` in the for loop condition.  It's possible that logically, the condition should be `y >= 0` to not run off the map edge.